# WPF Expand specific Expander inside Listview

Tags: wpf, listview, expander

I have a listview in which's groupstyle, i have defined an expander(code below), i programmatically add many items to the listview which get added to the appropriate expander and if the expander does not exist fo the new item, it gets created dynamically.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" >
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

So what needs to be done is that when a new item is added, the focus should divert to that item and the expander should be expanded while collapsing all else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a binding to see if the lists SelectedItem is part of the Group that we are bound to.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding}}" >
```

You will Bind IsExpanded to the lists SelectedItem, with a converter parameter that is bound to the viewmodel and have the converter simply check to see if the arguments match.

The converter simply returns true or false

```
public class yourConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((GroupItem)parameter).Contains(value);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You will have to help me a bit here, i'm not exactly a pro in WPF yet....what exactly do you mean, use a binding to see if the item is part of the group and the item i'm adding is not a selected item, it is newly created....thanks for the help though

Comment: Whatever you click or select in a list always sets the ListView.SelectedItem property. So all we do is check to see if what is selected is part of the current group in the converter and bind that to IsExpanded

Comment: but i'm not clicking on the new item...i'm adding a new item and for all i know the expander might not have been created or is collapsed, it is a new item/object that i'm adding....

Comment: Good point. But you can also set the SelectedItem to your new item after you have added it. With the above, just that change would then trigger the Bindings to re-evaluate and the expanders to expand/collapse as necessary.

Comment: i implemented this solution but it is giving me errors like " A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.", I have gone through many sol,utions most of which suggest multibindings but am not sure of it, can you help me through....

Comment: Certainly, can you post the code? Its very simple to switch to multibindings, but I'm not sure its needed.

Comment: the code is the same as posted in my question with the expander replaced by your expander code and the converter is declared in the .Resources section as it is a staticresource....thats it....i'm away from my PC right now.....will update my code in question when i get back home....

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to expand on the previous answer -- I am using this in an MVVM scenario, and was getting the same error as Billy mentioned above

> " A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

I ended up modifying the converter and XAML as so (the DataContext.CurrentItem is a placeholder for whatever is needed to reference the current item in the View Model):

```
public class MultiBindingItemsEqualConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool valuesEquals = values[0].Equals(values[1]);
        return valuesEquals;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

<Expander ...>
    <Expander.IsExpanded>
        <MultiBinding
            Mode="OneWay"
            Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindingItemsEqualConv}">
            <Binding
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView, AncestorLevel=1}"
                Path="SelectedItem"></Binding>
            <Binding
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView, AncestorLevel=1}"
                Path="DataContext.CurrentItem"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Expander.IsExpanded>
</Expander>
```

Comment: only thing i would add is that my convert function would read:
    bool rtn = true;
    object comparer = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
     rtn &= comparer.Equals(values[i]);

    return rtn;
that gives you easy expansion for checking the equality of multiple values