# Group ListView Items like a TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` which is starting to have too many items to have on one window. I would have a `ComboBox` to choose a subset to display, but all need to be available. I want to be able to collapse and expand logical portions of items, under parents. The number of groupings will be dynamic.

I need a `ListView` not a `TreeView` as the `ListView` defines a custom `ListBox`. To achieve this I followed this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/permanenttan/archive/2009/01/19/wpf-listview-with-check-boxes-and-no-clipping.aspx

To summarise, it is had two columns, the first contains a `CheckBox`, and the second contains a corresponding `TextBlock`. This is so I can select a row without checking the box.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.View>
     <GridView>
       column definintions....
```

It is the `<ListView.View>` which isn't available in `TreeView` which is why I believe I must stick with `ListView`.

Attempting to enclose the listview in a treeview didn't go well, it would result in me having to define separate listviews and therefore the whole column definition for each . As is my understanding. Avoiding a template too would be ideal but I would settle for this.

Ideally the `ObservableCollection` which populates the `ListView` can remain unchanged, I'd prefer not having a List of these.

Comment: Have you considered Expandars?  They collapse and expand.

Comment: @Blam Cheers! Relatively new to WPF. I'll post an answer if I achieve this.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576934/listview-jumps-or-does-not-shrink

Comment: I've been looking into this more. http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/ has been very helpful and has showed my `ListView.GroupStyle`. However I'm still stuck when it comes to splitting the collection into each group. I added an extra Property to the collection which contains an enum, I would like the collection to be split into groups based on the enum values.

Comment: My group style now looks like the code in the question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319398/wpf-expand-specific-expander-inside-listview. I like this, except I need to replace `ItemsPresenter` with a way of splitting my collection by the enum value.